# Managed Package error "Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation"

Tags: apex, managed-package, error, invalid

I'm getting an exception email from a client who has installed my `Managed Package` in his org. The error message I receive is:

> Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization:
>   xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx
>
> caused by: line 1, column 1: Dependent class is invalid and needs
>   recompilation: ContentController: Dependent class is invalid and needs
>   recompilation: System.test: line 32, column 17: Invalid type:
>   Component.Apex.Page

What puzzles me is that how can a Managed Package class be marked invalid since its already compiled and packaged, plus when I login to the org having the issue, and open the respective class `ContentController` and I found the code is hidden because its managed class, and the Status shows as `Valid` and not invalid.

How can I fix this error? I can verify in dev org that the class is absolutely correct and code saves fine, no compilation error when saving the class code.

Comment: Can you compile "All Apex Classes" and check again to see if this issue still exist?

Comment: At this point I don't have permission to the org experiencing the issue, and so was looking to understand the error message which reads `System.test: line 32, column 17: Invalid type: Component.Apex.Page` - Which I don't understand at all, these lines or code are not even used in my class.

Comment: I would open a case with Salesforce support as this may not be something you can diagnose and fix yourself. See [Compilation errors in the installed manager package](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005HuaIAE) which is the same error from a year ago with no resolution posted. Is your client seeing any errors?

Comment: Hi @VarunC. I'm facing a very similar problem (the last line in my stack trace is equal to yours: System.test: line 32, column 17: Invalid type: Component.Apex.Page) and described it here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005HuaIAE.

I still can't find a reason and good explanation for this. But, maybe, we'll find it together if we compare our situations. So, could you answer some questions posted below (I was not able to put them in 1 comment)?

Comment: A trigger for what object do you use? My one is on ContentDocument and fires after update.

Comment: Does penultimate line in your stack trace refer to any of you custom classes? Mine refers to the 1st line of one of my classes which is even not used in the trigger. It would be great if you share code of this class with me. Maybe, I'll find something similar with my class there. I can also share my file with you, if it's interesting for you.

Comment: I was able to get this exception in my developer org one time after I updated details of a Content Document in SF UI. UI shown "Internal Error" message to me and then I got the email with the exception. Have you been able to reproduce this error by yourself?

Comment: Mine trigger is on ContentVersion object and fires on update and insert both. And yes it does refer to a custom class which is also not part of trigger code but it refers it and strangely that class is compilable and is working just fine everywhere in my app. And No i could not reproduce this error myself in dev org or any of my test environments. It just randomly occur in customer orgs.

Comment: I had tried following up with sfdc support but they wont even look into it unless i purchase premier support :-(

Comment: @VarunC, my situation is the same (including contacting to sfdc support :)). Do you think you can somehow share code of your class that is referred in your stack trace?

Comment: I m afraid i cant share code of that class. But all i can confirm is, the class even has no relation or being called from the trigger. From my understanding, its a Platform bug and Error is mentioned in email System.test class in showing compilation error from salesforce and is part of platform schema and is jot able to identify Component.Apex.Page type ... The errornmessage has no relation to packaged trigger and has everything to do with platform itself breaking up.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that this is a platform bug too, but trying to find what causes the internal defect. It's pitty that you can't share the Apex class, but reasonable. In this case let me ask some questions regarding the code in it: 1) Is it a batch job (my class implements Database.Batchable<SObject>)? 2) Does it declare only 1 private constructor without parameters? 3) Does it call "Test.isRunningTest()" method somewhere?

Comment: No, my class is a simple apex class with utility static methods in it. There are no test methods in the class. The class only has methods like GetAllFields from sObject, or AddPageMessage stuff. All methods declared in this class are Static with no Batchable or Test methods interface or any constructor method.

Comment: OK. I give up :), because don't see any relation between our classes. Thank you for information.

Comment: @VarunC Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: nopes, still get error like this sometimes.